# Trying to add code to Wordpress website as a plugin, but only have css/js code not a zip folder

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins, flickity

I'm trying to add a slider to Wordpress (Flickity's slider: https://flickity.metafizzy.co) but am unable to figure out how to add it as it doesn't follow the typical external plugin format where I can add a zip folder.

Tried adding code into the text section of a post.
Tried setting up a custom css but not too sure I applied it correctly. Don't really know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

There are many slider plugins around already, you can use them to get inspiration. Look e.g. at [gutenslider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenslider/) that implements a slider block or at older plugins, e.g. [slide anything](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slide-anything/). As all wordpress plugins in the plugin dir must follow a GPL license, you can look at their source code.

That said, you can write your own plugin with flickity. You would have to give users a way to select which images they want to slide and then include the flickty stylesheets and javascript and make php create the needed Document Model for the slider.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template and call js and css using the wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style which is used Flickity's slider.And create html like this

HTML

```
<div class="main-carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
  <div class="carousel-cell">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Put jquery code in your template like below

```
$(document.ready(function()
{

    $('.main-carousel').flickity({
      cellAlign: 'left',
      contain: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because this is not a WordPress plugin. You do not need it to be one either. Place the files you have downloaded somewhere in the theme folder and then use `wp_enqueue_script` to load the JS files and `wp_enqueue_style` to load the CSS files.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: You may also want to consider using one of the *many* WordPress slider plugins if you are newer to WordPress. They do make things very simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a child-theme, then it is recommended that you do.  But here is what you will have to do: you need to edit files - such as header.php, footer.php, styles.css and the file where you would like you slider to go (page.php)

Add this to your header, just above styles.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
```

Add this code to your footer.php (I have also included jquery, you may not need to):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script> 

<script>
    $('.main-carousel').flickity({
      cellAlign: 'left',
      contain: true
    });
</script
```

This goes at the bottom of your styles.css:

```
  .carousel-cell {
 width: 100%; /*  full width */
  height: 300px;
  background: #222;
  /* center images in cells with flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel.is-fullscreen .carousel-cell {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And finally this is what displays your slider (this goes wherever you would like your slider to display - with link to the images you would like to use):

```
div class="main-carousel">
         <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1197x458"></div>
         <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1198x457"></div>
         <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1199x456"></div>
      </div>
```

You can see the slider in effect [here](https://hannedigital.com/wp/)